# C# Dictionary of arrays

Tags: c#, dictionary

Can I use C# Dictionary on classes like arrays??

```
Dictionary<double[],double[]>
```

I am afraid that it will not be able to tell when arrays are equal...

**EDIT:**

Will the hashing method in the dictionary take well care of arrays? or just hashing their references?

Comment: If you could satisfy my curiosity, what is the business need for having the key be an array?

Comment: I am collecting input-output pair (of large dimensionality) in a classification problem, where repeated pairs are averaged somehow before training classifier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For array keys, the dictionary willuse the references for hashing and equality, which probably isn't what you want. This leaves you with two choices: implement a wrapper class for `double[]`, or (better) write something that implements `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to the `Dictionary<T, T>` constructor.

Comment: @BlueRaja, does a `List<T>` do equality comparison and hashing over its contents? I don't think that it does.

Answer (score 3):

Only the array references will be compared.  In the following example, the dictionary will have *2* entries even though arrays a and b have the same number of entries and the entry values are equal:

```
double[] a = new[] { 1.0, 2.1, 3.2 };
double[] b = new[] { 1.0, 2.1, 3.2 };

Dictionary<double[], double[]> d = new Dictionary<double[], double[]>();

d[a] = new [] { 1.1 };
d[b] = new [] { 2.2 };

Console.WriteLine(d.Count);
Console.WriteLine(d[b][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having an array as the key is a good idea, especially if it's big and if your equality logic is based on the content of the array. Because every time you will call `GetHashCode`, it will have to perform calculations on the whole array, which can take some time if the array is big...

A solution would be to wrap the array in a class which would store the hashcode until the data is modified, so that it isn't recomputed every time :

```
class ArrayWrapper<T>
{
    private T[] _array;
    public ArrayWrapper(T[] array)
    {
        _array = array;
    }

    private int? _hashcode;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!_hashcode.HasValue)
        {
            _hashcode = ComputeHashCode();
        }
        return _hashcode.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        // Your equality logic here
    }

    protected virtual int ComputeHashCode()
    {
        // Your hashcode logic here
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _array.Length; }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _array[index]; }
        set
        {
            _array[index] = value;
            // Invalidate the hashcode when data is modified
            _hashcode = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So your dictionary would be a `Dictionary<ArrayWrapper<double>, ArrayWrapper<double>>`. Of course, you might want to add some methods or properties to the wrapper (implement `IList<T>` for instance)